# Is it possible to read this captcha with imagemagick/tesseract?

Tags: python, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract, captcha

I'm trying to read this captcha. I'm using ImageMagick to treat the image and Tesseract to interpret it. But without success. Could anyone help me?

```
convert captcha.png -fuzz -50% -transparent black -fuzz 15% -fill black -opaque 'rgb(16,128,176)' -fuzz 40% -fill white +opaque blue -colorspace gray captcha_clean.png

tesseract --psm 7 captcha_clean.png stdout
```

Should I use Python? Maybe you have a Python working example?

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Here is how to detect a black horizontal line and replace it with yellow color

```
    img = cv2.imread("JgqK4.png")
    (h, w) = img.shape[:2]
    img = cv2.resize(img, (w*2, h*2))

    blackMin = np.array([0,  0, 0],np.uint8)
    blackMax = np.array([0, 0, 0],np.uint8)
    HSV  = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(HSV, blackMin, blackMax)
    SE   = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (8,9))
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, SE, iterations=1)
    img[mask>0] = [0,255,255]
    cv2.imwrite("JgqK4_2.png", img)
```

Comment: As I understood it a bit similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806979/transparent-captcha-image-with-horizontal-line

Comment: You can't use the open-source popular OCR like tesseract or EasyOCR for this. The reason being a captcha is mostly used to check whether a physical, legitimate user is present on the client side or not. If any OCR could perform this task then the whole idea is rendered useless. In such cases, you may have to turn to deep learning methods or retrain existing OCR models that provide the end-to-end training pipeline.

Comment: These characters are not from standard font types. I would be surprised if any OCR tools like Tesseract could recognize them correctly and consistently even after preprocessing operations. One solution to this problem is to train a new DL model to recognize the characters from this specific captcha system like others have already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

CAPTCHA is an acronym for "completely automated public Turing test to tell computers and humans apart". This explains, why reading the text from a CAPTCHA by a machine is a very complex task - by intention.

OCR will only work for very simple CAPTCHA graphics.

If you really want to find a solution, you could train a machine-learning model, which will cost you a few hours for programming and training and quite a bit for the computing power needed - by intention.